# Google CSE multiple redefinements

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm using Google CSE and would like to use multiple redefinements in a query, e.g. q=search+term+more:redefinement1+more:redefinement2, however I can't seem to find this in the documentation. I know this works for one more:... but how can I specify multiple labels?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can't.

I've noticed that you can also specify a site to force the search, such as: "keyword1 keyword2 site:includesite.com", but you can't specify more than one.

Moreover, you can specify more than one excluded sites: "keyword1 keyword2 -site:includesite1.com -site:includesite2.com". I don't know why. :)