# Searching multiple labels in google CSE

Tags: seo, google-custom-search

I know it has been asked before: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690014/google-custom-search-using-multiple-search-labels-refinements), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408668/google-cse-multiple-redefinements). But I was reading the documents and saw it might be possible.

I need to add multiple refinements to the query in google custom search engine. So if I have multiple labels on my CSE, I would like to query a subset of them in a way. Say I have three labels: `news`, `articles` and `stories`. I would like to be able to search for a query like `earth` in all the pages included in `news` or `stories`.

For adding just one label, querying like this works fine: `earth more:news`. But no like when I add the second label.

**According to [google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search), you can use `OR` between multiple refinements.** But It does not work for me. I'm using [javascript and the RESTful APIs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest#rest_from_javascript) and yet I tried many combinations:

- `earth more:news more:stories`
- `earth more:news OR more:stories`
- `earth [more:news OR more:stories]`
- `earth more:news,stories`

Anyone has any ideas how it would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `AND` and `OR` options are only for pagemap data and meta-tags and they don't work on directory structures and labels.